# Laravel 5.4 reset password without email field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, password-recovery

How I can get email from password_resets tabled based on token? Because I need remove email field from reset password view.

I tried DB::table() but its still returns empty items array.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you need to remove email field from reset password view in the first place? How did you tried `DB::table()`? Please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

you can not select email using token. Because token is stored with Hashing, and every hash string generated from same token is different.

Laravel decrypt token by select it using email and then compare it with the plain token like this

```
if (Hash::check('plain_token', $hashed_token))
{

}
```

you can not do vice-versa.

hope, now you have clear the concept of reset password.

you can delete entries manually from database.